# How to debug an "Undefined Index" warning in PHP?

Tags: php

insert.php page

```
<body>
<h1>Insert Form</h1>
<p>This will be used to insert fields to the database</p>

<form name="insert_form" method="post" action="insertprocess.php">
t ID: <input name="testID" type="text" disabled><br>
t Name: <input name="testNAME" type="text"><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insertprocess.php page

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (test_ID, test_NAME) VALUES ('".$_POST['test_ID']."','".$_POST['test_NAME']."')");

?>
```

This is the error I get.

> Notice: Undefined index: test_ID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\insertprocess.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: test_NAME in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\insertprocess.php on line 4

Comment: just check isset $_POST variable

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, you should inform the community by choosing the correct answer. This will help future users.

Comment: The [mysql_* extension is deprecated](http://docs.php.net/intro.mysql) and will be removed in the upcoming version 7 of php, choose [another api](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to connect to your mysql server. Also have a read of http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I updated the post as I can't post again.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

`testNAME` is different from `$_POST['test_NAME']` the same applies to `testID` `$_POST['test_ID ']`.

Change to:

```
$_POST['testNAME']
$_POST['testID']
```